# TFS Link testresult to Task

Tags: testing, tfs

I have the next structure:

Bug

- Dev task
- Test Result with the failed test case
- Tested by

For retest the bug I have created a RETEST task and link it to the bug. When I rerun the testcase I would like to add the passed test result to the RETEST task. How can I do? Or what is the best workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a retest task for this case.

You could directly customize a workflow using **States** and **Reasons** for the Bug work item. Such as adding a state "Ready to Retest" for a Bug. And then assign this work item to the tester or tester group.  Suggest you to use the **Process Editor**, available with the download of **TFS Power Tools**. The Process Template Editor provides a graphical user interface for customizing work items (field, workflow and the form) and process templates.

More ways for customize the workflow for a process please refer the tutorial from MSDN:

- [Customize the workflow for a process](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/process/customize-process-workflow)
- [Add or modify a work item type](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/add-modify-wit)

Then you just need to directly **link test result to the bug workitem**. And in a Bug work item, you can click the **HISTORY--ALL CAHNGES** to track the history and process.

[image]